# why won't my file containing nexist compile

Tags: symbols, compiling, compilation-error

I am trying to use the 'does not exist' symbol in latex as it is defined [here](https://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols#Set_and.2For_logic_notation). I am using TeXstudio for mac.

This Latex file compiles fine:

```
\documentclass{article}\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
$\exists$
\end{document}
```

While this file won't compile

```
\documentclass{article}\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
$\nexists$
\end{document}
```

And gives me this error message

```
Undefined control sequence. $\nexists
```

In case this is relevent, I have included some information about the software and my computer:

About TeXstudio:
TeXstudio 2.12.8 (hg 2.12.8)
Using Qt Version 5.10.0, compiled with Qt 5.10.0 R
About my mac:
MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
macOS Catalina Version 10.15.4 (19E287)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `amssymb` in your preamble so you can use `\nexists`

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
$\nexists$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, this works, however I would also like to know why nexists is not included yet exists is. This distinction is not made clear on the website I linked to.

Comment: As I can see, it is not defined by LaTeX, so you should use a package. Use http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html to search LaTeX symbols (it also shows the packages needed to use the symbols)

Comment: I suppose that's because in LaTeX math typesetting you usually load the trio `amsmath, amssym. amsthm` so you don't care about most symbols.

Comment: ok thanks, this clears things up

Comment: The reason `\nexists` is not in the basic (La)TeX symbol set is historical.  The original symbol set included only what was needed for Donald Knuth's "The Art of Computer Programming".  When TeX became more widely used, additional symbols were created and made available by and for different disciplines -- mathematics, physics, linguistics, ..., as TeX was adopted by those communities.

Comment: @fred you may think exists and nexists have some relation and should go together, but tex just sees them as two symbols and the core tex fonts only have one of them so adding nexists is like adding cyrillic, you need to load an additional font. You could use \not\exits but that constructs an over-struck symbol so not as good.